# Can't read setting correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, backup, settings

I've recently remade the launcher of my game to WPF. While most of the code worked fine, one particular feature that I was working on broke completely when I moved it over.

The feature that I was working on is a simple backup system. The setup is simple: The user goes to the save manager and ticks the Automatic Backups setting. This is the XAML code of the tick:

```
  <CheckBox x:Name="AutoBackupCheckbox" Content="{x:Static  properties1:Resources.EnableBackupsString}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Checked="AutoBackupCheckbox_CheckChanged" Unchecked="AutoBackupCheckbox_CheckChanged" IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static properties1:Settings.Default},Path=AutoBackupEnabled}"/>
```

When the tick on the checkbox changes, this happens:

```
        private void AutoBackupCheckbox_CheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled = AutoBackupCheckbox.IsEnabled;
        MessageBox.Show(Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled.ToString());
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

The issue is that the code is firmly stuck on True. I have no idea what is forcing this setting. This renders the backup system always disabled, since, during debug, I always see the setting returning false when it's true.

Here's the code of what the launcher does at startup:

```
        {
        var jumperDeck = new JumpList();
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.StartGameJumpTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.QuickLoadJumpTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.SaveManagerTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.ResetLauncherLockTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.BugReporterJumpTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.EManualJumpTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.DiscordJumpTask);
        jumperDeck.JumpItems.Add(JumperCatalog.ReadmeJumpTask);
        JumpList.SetJumpList(Application.Current, jumperDeck);

        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        {
            var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
            var version = fvi.FileVersion;
            LauncherVersionLabel.Content = LauncherVersionLabel.Content + @" (" + version + @")";
        }
        GameVersionLabel.Content = GameVersionLabel.Content + @" (0.20.4-20180117)";
        var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
        //if (IsCompatible == false)
        //{
        //    Form osIncompatible = new IncompatibleVersion();
        //    osIncompatible.ShowDialog();
        //    Close();
        //}
        foreach (var arg in args)
            switch (arg)
            {
                case "-ResetLauncherLock":
                    Settings.Default.SkipLauncher = false;
                    Settings.Default.Save();
                    break;
                case "-NoLauncher":
                case "-QuickLoad":
                    if (!File.Exists(PlayerFile) || !File.Exists(RgssLib) || !File.Exists(InputPath))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.FileMissingLabelString, Properties.Resources.CriticalFailiureString, MessageBoxButton.OK,
                            MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    }
                    else if (arg == "-QuickLoad")
                    {
                        QuickLoad();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NormalStart();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        if (Settings.Default.SkipLauncher)
            if (!File.Exists(PlayerFile) || !File.Exists(RgssLib) || !File.Exists(InputPath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.FileMissingLabelString, Properties.Resources.CriticalFailiureString, MessageBoxButton.OK,
                    MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                NormalStart();
            }
        IoController.DiskCheck(CommonVariables.FolderCheck);
        if (!CommonVariables.IsDriveReady)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.DNRString, Properties.Resources.DNRTitle, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            Close();
        }
        if (CommonVariables.PermissionError || CommonVariables.SpaceError)
        {
            CanSaveLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.CommonWordNo;
            CanSaveLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;

            if (CommonVariables.PermissionError)
            {
                CanSaveLabel.Content = CanSaveLabel.Content + Properties.Resources.DiagnositcPermissionError;
                EngineErrorLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.BackupPermissionError;
            }
            else
            {
                CanSaveLabel.Content = CanSaveLabel.Content + Properties.Resources.DiagnosticSpaceError;
                EngineErrorLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.NotEnoughSpaceLabelString;
            }
            EngineErrorLabel.Visibility = CommonVariables.PermissionError ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            CanSaveLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.CommonWordYes;
            CanSaveLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }

        var gfMiss = 0;

        if (File.Exists(PlayerFile))
        {
            var gamever = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(PlayerFile);
            Rgss3PlayLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString + " " + @"(" + gamever.FileVersion + @")";
            Rgss3PlayLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            Rgss3PlayLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            Rgss3PlayLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            gfMiss = gfMiss + 1;
        }

        if (File.Exists(RgssLib))
        {
            var libver = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(RgssLib);
            Rgss3LibLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString + " " + @"(" + libver.FileVersion + @")";
            Rgss3LibLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            Rgss3LibLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            Rgss3LibLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            gfMiss = gfMiss + 1;
        }
        if (File.Exists(GameFile))
        {
            FileAvailiable.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString;
            FileAvailiable.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            FileAvailiable.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            FileAvailiable.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            gfMiss = gfMiss + 1;
        }
        if (File.Exists(InputPath))
        {
            var inputver = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(InputPath);
            InputLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString + @"(" + inputver.FileVersion + @")";
            InputLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            InputLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            InputLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            gfMiss = gfMiss + 1;
        }

        if (File.Exists(RgssExtFile))
        {
            var rex = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(RgssExtFile);
            RexVersionLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            RexVersionLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString +" (" + rex.FileVersion + ")";
        }
        else
        {
            RexVersionLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            RexVersionLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            gfMiss = gfMiss + 1;
        }

        if (File.Exists(CoreLibLocation))
        {
            var clx = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(CoreLibLocation);
            CoreLibraryLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.PresentString + " (" + clx.FileVersion + ")";
            CoreLibraryLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
        }
        else
        {
            CoreLibraryLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.MissingString;
            CoreLibraryLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            gfMiss += 1;
        }

        if (gfMiss > 0)
        {
            GfPresentLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.CommonWordNo;
            GfPresentLabel.Foreground = Brushes.DarkRed;
            EngineErrorLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.FileMissingLabelString;
            EngineErrorLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            PlayButton.IsEnabled = false;
            SkipSplashCheckbox.IsEnabled = false;
            DisableLauncherCheckbox.IsEnabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            GfPresentLabel.Content = Properties.Resources.CommonWordYes;
            GfPresentLabel.Foreground = Brushes.ForestGreen;
            if (!Directory.Exists(CommonVariables.SaveLocation))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(CommonVariables.SaveLocation);
                CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable = false;
            }
            else
            {
                CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable = NorthbridgeCommonTasks.GetFolderSaves();
            }
        }
        ExportButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        QuickLoadCommand.IsEnabled = CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        AutoBackupCheckbox.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        LocationBackup.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable && (bool)AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked;
        //ArchiveBckup.Enabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable && (bool)AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked;
        DeleteButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        TestBackupButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable &&
                                     AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked == true &&
                                     LocationBackup.Text != null;
        BuildZipCheckbox.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        BrowseButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable && AutoBackupCheckbox.IsEnabled;
        RestoreBackupButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable &&
                                        AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked == true;
        DeleteBackupButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && CommonVariables.IsSaveAvailable;
        ImportButton.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && !CommonVariables.PermissionError && !CommonVariables.SpaceError;
        GpuControl.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0;
        //SlotSelectCheckBox.Enabled = ImportButton.IsEnabled;
        ReadmeButton.IsEnabled = File.Exists(Ci == "el-GR" ? GreekReadme : ReadmeFile);
        AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked = Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled;
        SkipSplashCheckbox.IsChecked = Settings.Default.AcceleratedMode;
        if (!File.Exists(Directory.GetParent(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\RMVXA-GL.dll")) GpuControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        GpuControl.IsChecked = Settings.Default.EnableGPUAccelration;
        SingleBackupModeCheckbox.IsEnabled = gfMiss == 0 && (bool)AutoBackupCheckbox.IsChecked;
    }
```

And here's the code where it launches the game:

```
        private void NormalStart()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Hide();
        CommonProcedures.CheckDrive();
        GameInfo.Arguments = Settings.Default.AcceleratedMode ? "-playnow -astart" : "-playnow";
        if (!Settings.Default.EnableGPUAccelration) GameInfo.Arguments = GameInfo.Arguments + " -NoGPU";
        if (Settings.Default.CompatMode)
        {
            GameInfo.Arguments = GameInfo.Arguments + " -compatmode";
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Immortal Sins\\Config\\");
            IoController.DirectoryCopy(ConfigArea, "c:\\Immortal Sins\\Config\\", true);
        }
        _gameProcess.StartInfo = GameInfo;
        if (Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled && Settings.Default.AutoBackupLocation != null)
            BackupEngine.MonitorSetupCode();
        _gameProcess.Start();
        _gameProcess.WaitForExit();
        if (Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled && Settings.Default.AutoBackupLocation != null &&
            BackupEngine.CountChanges > 0 &&
            !Settings.Default.SingleBackupMode) BackupEngine.SnapshotBackupCode();
        else if (Settings.Default.AutoBackupEnabled && Settings.Default.AutoBackupLocation != null &&
                 BackupEngine.CountChanges > 0 && Settings.Default.SingleBackupMode && Settings.Default.ArchiveBackups)
            BackupEngine.SingleBackupArchive();
        if (Settings.Default.CompatMode)
        {
            IoController.DirectoryCopy("C:\\Immortal Sins\\Config\\", ConfigArea, true);
            Directory.Delete("C:\\Immortal Sins\\", true);
        }
        Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. There was another component that kept sending true (and false), because the data binding on that component was TwoWay, instead of OneWay. That, along with mike's solution fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsChecked`, not `IsEnabled`! `IsEnabled` is always true because it only checks if the checkbox is enabled. If a user checks the Checkbox you have to use the IsChecked Property.
Docs: [ToggleButton.IsChecked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_ToggleButton_IsChecked)